# How to run 2 commands one after other in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to run 2 perl commands with `sudo`-like `dzdo`, but somehow i am not able to achieve the result. Can someone help me with it.

This is the sample of my requirement. I have 2 scripts named `/home/user1/script1.pl` and `/home/user1/script2.pl`

Here, I have the condition to run the second script once the first script is executed successfully. So i tried using below ways but still fails.

```
cmd="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl && dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl";
```

```
cmd="dzdo -iHu admin "/home/user1/script1.pl" ; "/home/user1/script2.pl"";
```

```
cmd="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl" && "dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl";
```

```
cmd="dzdo -iHu admin "/home/user1/script1.pl ; /home/user1/script2.pl"";
```

```
cmd="$cmd1 && $cmd2";
```

```
cmd="${cmd1} && ${cmd2}";
```

I am getting the error as "Unknown option: ihu" for all the above methods. I even tried with many combinations but end with same error. I think i am missing some basic declaration. If i mention something as below, it runs the second script but not the first.

```
cmd1="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl";
cmd2="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl";
```

Both the scripts are running as expected if I run the scripts manually outside the perl scripting.

```
user1@123abc.dev.com > dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl ; dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl
```

Comment: Are you trying to run commands in perl (in which case there are lots of issues) or in (as it appears) shell (in which case the language the commands are written in doesn't matter and there are still issues)?

Comment: `iHu` or `ihu`?

Comment: And why say you're using `sudo` when you're using this `dzdo` instead (it appears to be something *like* `sudo` at least...)

Comment: Are you wanting to capture the output of the scripts or not?

Comment: The code snippets show variable assignments, some of them seem to have syntax errors, but there is no code that actually tries to execute a command. Please [edit] your question and show a [mre].

Comment: Finally i found an answer after some struggle. I am still learner :) I separated both the scripts as CMD1 and CMD2 and executed both the scripts after declaring CMD1 and CMD2. Like CMD1="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl"; $CMD1(next line) and CMD2="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl"; $CMD2(next line). This is doing the magic.. yayy Thanks for all of your support and answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I separated both the scripts as CMD1 and CMD2 and executed both the scripts after declaring CMD1 and CMD2.

```
CMD1="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl"; 
$CMD1
CMD2="dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl"; 
$CMD2
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP asked. It runs the second script unconditionally. (It's also a needlessly complicated way of doing what it does. You could simply write `dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script1.pl` and `dzdo -iHu admin /home/user1/script2.pl` on separate lines. None of that "CMD" junk.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm not familiar with `dzdo`, and I can't find documentation for it.

---

> I am getting the error as "Unknown option: ihu"

If it's the same options as `sudo`, `-ihu` doesn't make much sense. `-iHu`, which you said you were using, would make more sense.

If that's not the issue, I can't help more with this part. Consult its documentation. (`man dzdo`?) You could try passing them separately (`-i -H -u`).

---

> I am trying to run 2 perl commands with `sudo`-like `dzdo`

If it's like `sudo`, it takes a program and arguments to pass to the program.

So what you want could be achieved using the following (once you get the issue with the options resolved):

```bash
dzdo -iHu admin /usr/bin/sh -c '/home/user1/script1.pl && /home/user1/script2.pl'
```

Comment: Thats right. dzdo -iHu is like sudo. I made it working by executing the CMD variables after declaring. For ex, $CMD1 and $CMD2.